# I want custom json format from given json value using javascript for loop

Tags: node.js, for-loop

My JSON:

```
[
  {
    app_id: 1,
    app_name: 'app1',
    active: true,
    created_at: null,
    created_by: null,
    updated_at: null,
    updated_by: null
  },
  {
    app_id: 1,
    app_name: 'app2',
    active: true,
    created_at: null,
    created_by: null,
    updated_at: null,
    updated_by: null
  }
]
```

I want custom format as below using JavaScript `for` loop. I have tried but I'm new so unable to got perfect result.

Result which I want:

```
[
  {
    app_id: 1,
    app_name: 'app1',
    active: true
  },
  {
    app_id: 1,
    app_name: 'app2',
    active: true }
]
```

[Showing Error Which I have tried pls click and see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQmFc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to use a `for` loop? You might want to take a look at [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const result = values.map(value => ({ app_id: value.app_id, app_name: value.app_name, active: value.active }));
```

**Edit:** According your error:

Try `id: app_options[i].id` instead of `app_option[i].id`. You could also use a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop.

Answer (score -1):

var formdata = [];

for (var i = 0; i <2 ; i++) {
      formdata.push({
        keyId: keyId,
        labelName: labelName,
        fieldName: fieldName,
      });
    }

Comment: Please use code styles and indentations for your code.